# OneLogin - how do I redirect to a custom login page upon session expiration?

Tags: onelogin

According to the [OneLogin documentation](https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/1/samples/login-user-via-api#nomfa), I can use my own login form combined with their API to log users in.  And that works fine until the session expires.  At that point, the next communication to the server redirects me to OneLogin's login page and not mine.  Is it possible to redirect users back to my login page upon expiration?  I'd really prefer not to confuse users by showing more than one login screen.

I have tried some tricks where I attempt to intercept the redirects within servlet calls but then I run into issues between the browser and cross domain cookies.  More importantly, I think that is against OneLogin's intended usage of the API.  So I'm hoping someone in the know could shed some light on a more proper way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What sort of flow are you using when you get redirected to to login page?

The expected pattern for using the login endpoint is to build a 'facade' on top of the OneLogin ui.

Basically you use the Create Login Token dance to establish a session with OL, and then relying on the Embed apps API to build your own version of the OL application portal (https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/1/samples/csharp/embed-apps) - and specifically calling the https://app.onelogin.com/client/apps/launch/ endpoint in order to invoke other applications.

I'm guessing this is how you're then launching applications secured by OneLogin.

Having said all that, if you go into your OneLogin Account settings (only visible if you're the account owner) you can configure where users should be redirected to when their session expires through the **Logout Url** setting.

Configure that to point to your custom Login page and you should be good to go on session expiration.

Comment: I tried the **Logout Url**.  Setting that seems to only redirect my page when I manually click the logout button.  However, say I have two pages open: one is a custom page with a button that uses the OL API to launch QuickBooks and on the other page I am logged in to the OL dashboard.  I now click 'logout' on the OL dashboard.  Then I switch to the other page and click my launch button.  My session is gone and I am redirected to <mysubdomain>.oneLogin.com login page (which is not what I set **Logout Url** to).  That is what I would like to see if I can change.

Comment: Is the page that is redirecting you the OneLogin's log-in page the https://app.onelogin.com/client/apps/launch/ page? If so, this may well be a bug.

Can you give me a few more details on your overall goals for this? Are you basically trying to "whitelable" (or hide) all the details about the underlying OneLogin account for you users in favor of your own UI, or are you trying to work in a sort of "mixed mode" (some folks use this as a convenience mechanism to launch multiple application)

Thanks!

Comment: The link redirecting me is: https://app.onelogin.com/launch/{app-id}.  I am not using the embed call - I don't even have a token for that.  My goals are to (yes, sorry - no offense) hide OneLogin completely, use my own login page to log users in and display my own app portal.

Comment: So you're basically using OneLogin to maintain user login records? We don't mind :)

My recommendation is continue to use the launch API and I've got an enhancement request in to development to have that page direct users to the custom logout page when the session expires. 

It will probably involve passing a new parameter to the API as  flag to trigger it (so as not to change the _existing_ behavior) so I'll keep you posted.

Comment: I'm researching OneLogin for its SSO capability while still attempting to maintain as much control as I can over the front end.  If we can do what we need to, we will potentially be importing a significant # of users in the near future.  Fortunately, your API is just what we were looking for.  My thanks for the enhancement request; it sounds like that will do the job very nicely.

Comment: Hey there. 

Just to let you know, we'd added an enhancement to honor the logout URL on session expiration:

http://app.onelogin.com/launch{app-id}?useLogOutUrl=true

This should redirect properly to the logout URL. This is currently live!

Comment: Hey @JohnOffenhartz how about if you never installed OneLogin to begin with, and all of your mail clients become unusable because it has taken over your authentication and every time the mail clients wants you to auth against gmail, OneLogin redirects you to its own login that you don't have an account for. How, pray tell, does one uninstall this malware?

Comment: Sounds like someone configured your Gmail client to SSO using one login. This requires admin permissions, so ask around with your admins. You're supposed to set up at least one account to NOT use SSO so you can get out of the pickle you're in, but barring that contact google support and they should be able to disable it. Nice Tom Waits quote BTW.